# Django models file field regex?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to be able to check if the files that are going to be uploaded through forms contain any sensitive information. Can someone please give me an idea on how I can accomplish this.

This is my code.

Models.py

```
class File(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    doc = models.FileField(upload_to='files/docs/', validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['pdf','docx'])])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

My upload code in views.py

```
def upload_file(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES) #request.Files handles file uploads
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            file_dlp()
            return redirect('file_list')
        
    else:
        form = FileForm()

    return render(request, 'upload_file.html', {
        'form':form
    })
```

Comment: What do you mean by "contain sensitive information"? This is very broad and could mean anything depending on what your use case it. What isn't working with your current code - what do you want to happen that isn't currently happening?

Comment: @solarissmoke I want to create a simple data loss prevention function that checks those files when they are about to be uploaded. I will flag sensitive information using regex. The information will be chosen by me. The current code is working fine and the files are being uploaded. The problem I am facing is that I cannot call fildfeilds. Like lets say I want to make a function where if the title is 1 print (1). How do I accomplish this. Can you give me an advise.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "I cannot call fildfeilds. Like lets say I want to make a function where if the title is 1 print (1)" - please try to clarify what you mean by editing your question.

Comment: @solarissmoke I cannot call this file field (doc = models.FileField) from models.py in my view.py. The file is being uploaded through file forms but I want to make another function that calls only this specific file field.